# Facebook getUrl returns 0 PHP SDK Codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I trying to figure this out for hours now and i have tried every post available.

1. Im not using Javascript SDK. Im only using PHP SDK and its the latest.
2. I have the newest certificate downloaded from github and i have included the same.
3. Sandbox is disabled

Im creating a new facebook library

```
<?php

include(APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');
class Fbconnect extends Facebook
{
public $user = NULL;
public $user_id = NULL;
public $fb = false;
public $fbSession = false;
public $appkey = 0;
public $tests = 5;

public function Fbconnect()
{

    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->config('facebook', TRUE);
    $config = $ci->config->item('facebook');
    parent::__construct($config);

    $this->user_id = $this->getUser();
    $me = NULL;


    if($this->user_id)
    {
        try
        {
            $me = $this->api('/me');
            $this->user = $me;
            $tests = $this->user_id;
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e)
        {
            error_log($e);
        }
    }

}
}
```

My login controller

```
public function facebook_request()
{
    $this->load->library('fbconnect');
    $data = array(
        'redirect_uri' => site_url('login/handle_facebook_login'),
        'scope' => 'email , user_birthday, user_interests'

    );

    redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($data));
}

public function handle_facebook_login()
{
    $this->load->library('fbconnect');
    if($this->fbconnect->user)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->fbconnect->user);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'could not login<br/>';

        var_dump($this->fbconnect->user_id);

        echo '<br/>' ; echo  $this->fbconnect->tests; echo '<br/>' ; var_dump($this->fbconnect->tests);
    }

}
```

I have defined my appId and secret in /config/facebook.php.

Here's the output:

```
could not login
int(0) 
5
int(5)
```

Comment: Are you sure the library is being loaded?

Comment: Well, im echoing $this->fbconnect->tests which is present in facebook library. CI would give me PHP error right if it wasn't laded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that facebook requires a **'/' - forward slash** at the end in the **siteurl** field in app dashboard.

Most of the sites add it automatically. But not in this case.

Hope it helps others!